# Unity2D: Why won't a variable from a different script update in this script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, variables

Here's the first script which is just for the gems to be "collected".

```
using UnityEngine;
public class GemDestructionScript : MonoBehaviour
{
public int gemsCollected = 0;

void Awake()
{
}

void Update()
{
}

void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
{
if (col.gameObject.tag.Equals("Player1"))
{
gemsCollected++;
GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().enabled = false;
GetComponent<CircleCollider2D>().enabled = false;
}
}
}
```

This is the 2nd script which is for the `gemsCollected` to be displayed on the canvas.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System;
public class GemCounter : GemDestructionScript
{
private Canvas canvas;

void Start()
{
}

void Update()
{
Transform child = transform.Find("Text");
Text t = child.GetComponent<Text>();
t.text = Convert.ToString(gemsCollected);
}
}
```

The problem is that the `gemsCollected` variable doesn't update on the canvas, it just stays at 0 the whole time.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fail to see the need for GemCounter to inherit from GemDestruction. Inheritance is more commonly used when having different Categories build upon each other.

A good, simple example of this is the Fruit example from [Unity](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/inheritance)

In your case I would recommend using 2 separate Classes that are not linked via Inheritance. This will save you the headache of properly accessing whatever Data you need, unless it's really important for you to use Inheritance.

When you've split the classes and moved your `gemsCollected` to the Counter, instead of on the Gems themselves, you can just have the Gems "report in" when they are collected. This way the Counter can keep track of how many Gems have been collected and displays them on the UI. Every Object should have their job, and only use things that are relevant for that Job.

Example:

```
public class GemDestructionScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    GemCounter counter;

    private void Start()
    {
        // Find where-ever you keep the GemCounter Script (the Canvas in your case)
        counter = GameObject.Find("Canvas").GetComponent<GemCounter>();
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject.tag.Equals("Player1"))
        {
            counter.AddGem();
            GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().enabled = false;
            GetComponent<CircleCollider2D>().enabled = false;
        }
    }
}

public class GemCounter : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int gemsCollected = 0;

    Text GemCounterText;

    private void Start()
    {
        // Finding the Text Object in every Frame would be inefficient, so unless that object is constantly changing, just get it once during Start/Awake/before using it
        GemCounterText = GameObject.Find("Text").GetComponent<Text>();
    }

    public void UpdateGemCount()
    {
        GemCounterText.text = gemsCollected.ToString();
    }

    public void AddGem()
    {
        gemsCollected++;
        UpdateGemCount();
    }
}
```

Comment: For some reason now it wont show up at all not even the zero no errors are being shown either, and i don't think I explained my self fully every time a gem is destroyed the counter on the top right of the screen gets +1 atleast that is how its supposed to work.

Comment: Edited the Code of my Answer according to your new Info according to your comments. Every Object you have should have a Job and it only does that Job. Your Counter keep count and displays the total Gems collected. Your Gems register that they got collected and tell the Counter that they have been collected, then disappear. What you don't want/need is for every single Gem (even if they are already collected and gone) to keep count of how many have been collected. If you happen to have 100 Gems, all of them are holding onto Info that is irrelevant to their function in the Scene.